# Null value handle for sharepoint

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I need to do  null value handling for setting sharepoint list column. So, I am using ternary operator for same. I am using client object model(jQuery/sp.js)

```
myVar == null ? "" : myVar
```

In browser when I see column value it come blank space but when I viewing value using rest end point

field value is coming null

```
"UserCity": null,
```

Instead, I want

```
"UserCity":""
```

Comment: can you share some more code/description ...... Because there is nothing wrong with your ternary operator..

Comment: @RohitWaghela I am using code from MSDN site only https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx  during debugging I found it is setting as oListItem.set_item('UserCity', ""');

Comment: What is the column type for which you need null handling

Comment: @sunilsahu single line of text

Answer (score 0):

Hi to assign value handling null you can use "Conditional assertion"

```
myVar = myVar || "";
```

And i don't think so it might be giving you null infact it be like

```
<UserCity m:null="true" />
```